# How do I find street segments using the Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geospatial

In Google Map Maker you can right click on an area and select "Find near this point" which shows a list of every road segment and intersection nearby. Is there any way in the google maps API to retrieve similar information regarding road segments?

I'm working on a simple exercise app and need to know how many blocks I've traveled, not just distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Maps API does not offer the ability to query for road features directly.